# ajax json table grouping row

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Tell me please. I just started learning ajax and would like to ask for a more detailed explanation (if possible). The problem is as follows, I receive JSON from the server of the following type

```
{"JsonResult":[{"Name":"Иванов Иван Иванович","Email":"IvanovII","Title":"Что-то еще","Department":"IT"}
```

and output them through:

````
 function getData() {var $tbl = $('#tblInfo');
$.ajax({
    url: $("#Get").val(),
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $tbl.empty();

        $.each(data.JsonResult, function (i, model) {
            $tbl.append
                (
                '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + model.Name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + model.Email + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + model.Title + '</td>' +
                '<tr>'
                );
        });
    }
});```
````

Everything works, the only thing I want to do is nested lines, but I don’t know how to do it. That is, iterate over the **Department** and list everyone who is related to it ..
This is what I am trying to achieve
[Grouping Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M503w.png)

Comment: Can you show entire json structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the anonymous function in the `success` object with the one shown below:

```js
// Simulate some data for the purpose of testing:
const data = {"JsonResult":[
  {"Name":"Iron Man", "Email": "IM", "Title": "Rocket", "Department": "Super Heroes"},
  {"Name":"Иванов Иван Иванович", "Email":"IvanovII", "Title":"Что-то еще", "Department":"IT"},
  {"Name":"Wonder Woman", "Email": "WW", "Title": "Wonder", "Department": "Super Heroes"},
  {"Name":"Bill Gates", "Email":"BG", "Title":"Coder", "Department":"IT"}
]};

// For purpose of testing, assign the anonymous function to a
// variable so that it can be invoked.
const success = 

function (data) {
  const $tbl = $("#tblInfo");
  // $tbl.empty();

  data = data.JsonResult; // to reduce typing

  // First sort the data by Department
  data.sort((a,b) => a.Department<b.Department ? -1 : 1);
    
  let dept = "";
  data.forEach(model => {
    if (dept !== model.Department) {
        dept = model.Department;
        $tbl.append("<tr><th colspan='3'>" + dept + "</th></tr>");
    }
    $tbl.append('<tr><td>' + model.Name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + model.Email + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + model.Title + '</td></tr>'
               );
  });
}

// Test the function:
success(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tblInfo" border="1">
 <thead><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Title</th></thead>
</table>
```

Your `data.JsonResult` is a Javascript array. A native method for iterating through each element in an array is `forEach`.

To do grouping in the Html table, the data should be sorted by the grouping attribute, ie `Department`. I then use a variable `dept` to detect when the `Department` in the next row of data has changed.

---

To answer your additional requirement given in the comment, modify the sorting algorithm as follows:

```js
// Simulate some data for the purpose of testing:
const Data = {"JsonResult":[
  {"Name":"Steve Jobs", "Title": "Administrator", "Department": "IT"},
  {"Name":"Иванов Иван Иванович", "Title":"Programmer", "Department":"IT"},
  {"Name":"Wonder Woman", "Title": "Administrator", "Department": "IT"},
  {"Name":"Bill Gates", "Title":"Coder", "Department":"IT"}
]};

const $tbl = $("#tblInfo");
let data = Data.JsonResult; // to save typing & reduce clutter

data.forEach(m => {
  $tbl.append(`<tr><td>${m.Name}</td><td>${m.Title}</td><td>${m.Department}</td></tr>`);
});

const sort = (button) => {
  /************Include this block**************************/
  const sortOrder = [ "Coder", "Programmer", "Administrator" ];
  const findIndex = value => sortOrder.findIndex(i => i == value);
  /********************************************************/
 
  /*************Replace the sort body**********************/
  data.sort((a,b) => {
    const ai = findIndex(a.Title);
    const bi = findIndex(b.Title);
    return ai - bi;
  });
  /********************************************************/
  
  const sorted = $("#sorted");
  data.forEach(m => {
  sorted.append(`<tr><td>${m.Name}</td><td>${m.Title}</td><td>${m.Department}</td></tr>`);
});
  button.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Unsorted original data</h2>
<table id="tblInfo" border="1">
 <thead><th>Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Department</th></thead>
</table>

<p>
 <button onclick="sort(this)">Sort now!</button>
</p>

<h2>Sorted data</h2>
<table id="sorted" border="1">
 <thead><th>Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Department</th></thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks bro! And you can't tell me how to sort the table according to a certain algorithm. More precisely, the Title column. I want to do something like this:
In each department, the first were Coders, then Programmers, and only then system administrators. These are all approximate data

Comment: @Азат Your additional requirement has no relation to the title of your original question. It is about sorting which is a different topic altogether. Anyway, I have added the solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the question is off topic. Your sorting works without problems if you do not first group by Department value. But if you group and then sort by position in each Department, something that is not clear to me happens ((

Comment: @Азат Sorting can also be done at the database, probably more efficient. For example, in Sql, it can be done by simply `ORDER BY Department, Title`. You should work with the backend people to have the data sorted in the way you want. Even if you want to do it in Javascript it is still possible, by say sorting multiple rounds. If Title is unique among all Departments, then sorting by Title will always mean the data will be grouped by Department.

Comment: Yes, you speak correctly as always. thanks